# Avoiding loss-of-significance errors by rewriting function.

Tags: numerical-methods

I was given $f(x)=\sin{(a+x)}-\sin{a}$, for values of $x$ very close to 0. The problem seems to be subtracting two numbers very close to each other. Could I get around this by re-writing as $$f(x)=2\cos{\left(a+\frac{x}{2}\right)}\sin{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}? $$

Comment: An important lesson for you: Use parentheses. I first thought that you mean 
$$
f(x) = \sin(a) +x - \sin(a)
$$
which is just $x$, but apparently you mean
$$
f(x) = \sin(a+x)-\sin(a)
$$

Comment: @MattiP. Noted thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Depending on $a$, for general values the first expression will have 15 correct digits after the decimal dot. However, when giving the accuracy of the result one is more interested in the relative accuracy and thus does not count the leading zero digits of the difference. This relative accuracy will deteriorate with small $x$.

This problem you do not have in the second expression, as the sine evaluation is done as $\sin(x)=x\cdot (1+x^2⋅s_1(x^2))$, so that close to zero it converges to the correct approximation $\sin x\approx x$, giving accurate results. This accuracy is not lost in the multiplication.